# UITableView iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to make this app (my first iPhone app) that I think should use UITableViews. What I am wanting this app to do is for a user to select a state that is listed on the first screen, then on the next screen the user will select an area in that state. On the next screen the user will choose a grade(V0-V10) and that will send them to a screen that lists the climbs in that grade.

I think a UITableView makes sense to use, but I am not entirely sure. I am very new to this so I would like some of y'alls opinions on what way to make this in the way that makes most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UITableViews are the way to go, I would highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/), it will get you up to speed with the basics,

From my experience the best way to learn iOS dev is to keep doing tutorials until it all makes sense to you.
So find a project you like (like like you did), and find something that does a similar thing, internet is full of help.

make sure to set the delegate and data source to the correct view though (in interface builder, click on the tableview, then ctrl+click and drag to the yellow shape at the bottom of the view, it will ask if you mean datasource or delegate

Good luck!

Comment: I have looked online, do you know of any tutorials that show you how to have more than one UITableView in an app?

Comment: It should be the exact same, when you have more than one view, you just replicate the process, but for the other view controller, make sure to set the delegate and data source to the correct view though (in interface builder, click on the tableview, then ctrl+click and drag to the yellow shape at the bottom of the view, it will ask if you mean datasource or delegate, I can't help with more than that, unless i see whats going on, but let me look for 2 table views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use UITableViews with a UINavigationController.  That approach is very common and is used in apps like Settings and Mail.

Comment: I have started the process and got stuck on adding another table view, I have the list of states and when I press "Alabama" it pulls up the list of areas, but when I press the area it doesn't send me to the next screen?

Comment: May I see the code that is supposed to transition from the areas to the next screen?